Why won't service map start on my AS/400e?
I'm attempting to connect to an AS/400e server running OS/400 V4R3M0 from a Windows XP machine using AS/400 Client Access V3R2M0. Although I can ping and telnet into the server on port 23, I encounter the following errors when testing the connection in Client Access:

Please note that all the following messages are translated from Italian, so they may differ from the standard Client Access and OS/400 error templates.

- Winsock error, connect function return code 10061
- Unable to connect to the server mapper (port 449) on the AS/400E system
- Communication error during the validation of confidentiality information on the AS/400E system

These errors suggest the "service map" server (as-svrmap), which should run on port 449, isn't active. My NETSTAT *CNN output confirms nothing is listening on port 449:
Remote           Remote     Local
addr.            port       port       T. inat.  State
...
*                *          telnet     000:00:35  Listening
*                *          tftp       000:19:09  *UDP
*                *          1026       000:19:08  *UDP
*                *          as-cent >  000:19:29  Listening
...

Attempts to start the server with STRHOSTSVR SERVER(*SVRMAP) RQDPCL(*TCP) do not change this, and DSPJOBLOG shows:
3 > STRHOSTSVR SERVER(*SVRMAP) RQDPCL(*TCP)
    The routing entry with sequence number 2541 already exists.
    The comparison value is in conflict with routing entry 2541.
    The job 604638/QUSER/QZSOSMAPD has been submitted to the job queue QSYSNOMAX in the library QSYS.

I believe this is a standard warning which can be ignored since other services show similar messages on startup but successfully list in NETSTAT *CNN.
Furthermore, DSPLOG revealed that QZSOSMAPD starts and stops within a second:
CPF1124  00  INFO.    Job 604526/QUSER/QZSOSMAPD started on 21/02/24 at 15:46:32 in the subsystem QSYSWRK in QSYS. Job entered into the system on 21/02/24 at 15:46:32.
CPF1164  00  COMPLET.   Job 604526/QUSER/QZSOSMAPD ended on 21/02/24 at 15:46:32; took 1 second; exit code 0.

This abrupt stopping is likely why as-svrmap isn't appearing in NETSTAT *CNN. However, the reason behind this behavior remains unclear.
Finally, after listing the installed licensed programs with GO LICPGM -> 10, I verified the key related products using CHKPRDOPT PRDID(<PRDID>), all of which reported no errors.
I'm running out of troubleshooting ideas — any suggestions on how to resolve this connection issue? Thank you!

Very well debugged! Did you try to STRHOSTSVR SERVER(*ALL) for a brute force attempt against dependency hell?

Yes, I have performed multiple IPLs on both A and B, restarted the Ethernet line, the TCP service, and associated servers, as well as all "Client Access" services. Specifically, for STRHOSTSVR, I have attempted restarts both with and without the RQDPCL(*TCP) parameter.

what does DSPJOBLOG 604526/QUSER/QZSOSMAPD show?

The system says there's no such file.
